# Expression for $\nabla_{JX} Y$ on a Kähler manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $(M, \omega, g, J)$ be a Kähler manifold with symplectic form $\omega$, Riemannian metric $g$ and complex structure $J$.

I'm looking for a formula that gives an expression for $\nabla_{J X} Y$, where $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita connection and $X, Y$ are (real) vector fields on $M$.
Actually, what I want to calculate is $\nabla_{JX} T$ where $T$ is some arbitrary tensor (but I guess this can be reduced to the case where $T$ is a vector field by the Leibniz identity).

Comment: Calculate in terms of what, exactly? I mean, what quantities would you allow in your formula?

Comment: Sorry that my question is a bit vague. I did a longer calculation and this term $\nabla_{JX}$ popped up and I cannot find a way to handle it. So I was hoping to get some inspiration of how this term can be rewritten/simplified. This question has some connection to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571384/does-the-complex-structure-of-a-k%c3%a4hler-manifold-preserves-the-lie-algebra-of-sym

Comment: My concern is that a term like $\nabla_{JX}Y$ is already fairly simple...

Answer (score 3):

Here's one alternative expression.

As $\nabla$ is torsion-free, we have $\nabla_{JX}Y - \nabla_Y(JX) - [JX, Y] = 0$, so

$$\nabla_{JX}Y = \nabla_Y(JX) + [JX, Y] = (\nabla_YJ)X + J(\nabla_YX) + [JX, Y] = J(\nabla_YX) + [JX, Y]$$

since $\nabla J = 0$ as $g$ is Kähler.